# How to determine whether a single swap is sufficient to sort an array of integers.?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Here is the code snippet, which is not efficient, please provide an efficient way of solving this:

This method returns true, if array is sorted using just single swap.
This method returns false, if array requires more than one swap operation to sort.

```
public boolean sortArrayWithSingleSwapIfPossible() {
        int[] A = {1, 5, 3, 3, 2, 6};
        int temp;
        int swapCount = 0;
        int length = A.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            if (i == length - 1) {
                break;
            }
            if (A[i] > A[i + 1]) {
                if (((i + 2) < length) && A[i + 1] == A[i + 2]) {
                    temp = A[i];
                    A[i] = A[i + 2];
                    A[i + 2] = temp;
                    ++swapCount;

                } else {
                    temp = A[i];
                    A[i] = A[i + 1];
                    A[i + 1] = temp;
                    ++swapCount;
                }
            }

            if (swapCount > 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: If the code is working as intended, this may be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It depends on the algorithm you use

Comment: what kind of swap? the swap of consequent elements or the swap of any two elements ?

Comment: @mangusta
The swap operation that will sort the array. There is no constraint on the type of swap whether consequent or swap of the two elements.
e.g
1, 5, 3, 3, 6, 7  this array can be sorted using single swap only, hence returns true.

1, 3, 3,6, 7, 5 this array can not be sorted using single swap, hence returns false.

Comment: the code snippet that you provided is not correct because it counts more than one swap, whereas it is sufficient to swap 5 and 2. there is a difference between efficiency and correctness ;-)

Comment: Given `[5, 7, 3]`. That will not sort, and is single swap.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this `O(N)` solution.

> 1. start from Left, find the first out of order element. `O(N)`
> 2. start from right, find the first out of order element. `O(N)`
> 3. swap these two
> 4. now check if the array is Sorted. `O(N)`

```
public yourFunction(){
   int[] input = {1,5,3,3,2,6};
   int leftIndex = findLeftIndex(input);
   int rightIndex = findRightIndex(input);
   if( leftIndex == rightIndex || leftIndex ==-1 || rightIndex == -1)
       return false; // check these edge cases just to be on safe side.
   swap(input,leftIndex,rightIndex);
   return isSorted(input)
}

private int findRightIndex(int[] input) {
   for(int i=input.length -1 ; i>=1 ;i--){
      if(input[i-1] > input[i]){
        return i;
      }
   }
   return -1;
}

private int findLeftIndex(int[] input) {
    for(int i=0 ; i<(input.length-1) ;i++){
       if(input[i] > input[i+1]){
        return i;
       }
    }
    return -1;
} 

public boolean isSorted(int[] a){
   for(int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i ++){ 
     if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
       return false; 
     }
   }
   return true; 
}
```

In your example,

1. you will find `5`
2. you will find `2`
3. swap `5,2` - > `{1,2,3,3,5,6}`
4. check if the array is sorted, it's sorted so return `true`.

**UPDATE**

If there are duplicate `left_out_of_order` elements or `right_out_of_order` elements, you might have to swap the leftmost `left_out_of_order` element with the rightmost `out_of_order_element`.

So your `findLeftIndex()` and `findRightIndex()` method will change as following:

```
private int findRightIndex(int[] input) {
   for(int i=input.length -1 ; i>=1 ;i--){
      if(input[i-1] > input[i]){
        while(i<input.length-1 && input[i] == input[i+1]){
           i++;
        }
        return i;
      }
   }
   return -1;
}

private int findLeftIndex(int[] input) {
    for(int i=0 ; i<(input.length-1) ;i++){
       if(input[i] > input[i+1]){
        while(i>0 && input[i] == input[i-1]){
           i--;
        }
        return i;
       }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I would add to step 3 that we swap and move to step 4 in case if left "out-of-order" element is larger than right one. otherwise we return false

Comment: Check the comment by Joop Eggen underneath the question. I think his scenario is not solved by this algorithm?

Comment: @Timo why do you think so? This works even for `{5,7,3}`

`left_out_of_order element = 3` 
`right_out_of_order element = 3`. In code I handled this with `leftIndex == rightIndex`. Even If you don't write that, it will work fine. You will swap `3,3` without any effect and check if the array is sorted, it's not ... so return `false`.

Comment: @karthik You are right in how the scenario plays out. And the way the OP defined a swap makes placing 3 at the first index and shifting the rest not a valid operation. The comment by Joop is more a question if this is a "smart" algorithm or not, which was not the original question.

Comment: @kartik -Thanks.. i have to only implement swap method right in your solution

Comment: @kapiljain Yes, just swap  `input[leftIndex]` with `input[rightIndex]` in that method.

Comment: @karthik Your program is giving wrong result for this input.
[1,5,3,3,7] it is returning false. But it must return true, it can be sorted with just one swap.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Simple approach

1. Copy to new array and sort
2. Compare with original array if any differences divide with 2 ~ swap times

   ```
   static boolean checkSorted(int n, int arr[])
   {
       // Create a sorted copy of original array
       int []b = new int[n];
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
           b[i] = arr[i];
       Arrays.sort(b, 0, n);

       // Check if 0 or 1 swap required to
       // get the sorted array
       int ct = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
           if (arr[i] != b[i])
               ct++;
       if (ct/2 < 2)
           return true;
       else
           return false;
   ```

   }

[source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-array-can-be-sorted-with-one-swap/)

Solution 2: More effective.

1. Travel from left to right
2. If found a reverse case, swap with min value of the rest (using TreeMap to sort while keeping its index)
3. Increase swap counter
4. Continue traveling
5. If found a reverse case return false
6. Return true if don't find any cases.

   private static boolean test2(int[] inputs) {
   int swapCounter = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length - 1; i++) {
   if (inputs[i] > inputs[i+1]) {
   if (swapCounter > 0) return false;
   TreeMap map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
   for (int j = i + 1; j < inputs.length; j++) {
   map.put(inputs[j], j);
   }
   int minIndex = (int)map.firstEntry().getValue();
   int temp = inputs[i];
   inputs[i] = inputs[minIndex];
   inputs[minIndex] = temp;
   swapCounter++;
   }
   }
   return true;
   }